# Looping through API results for pagination

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm trying to access some data via an API.  Here's my current code:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://api.example.com/rest/1.3/analytics/affiliate/vendor/?account=xxxxx&select=EARNINGS_PER_HOP");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Page: 1', 'Accept: application/json', 'Authorization: XXXXX'));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($response) {
    $array = json_decode($response, TRUE);

    foreach ($array['rows']['row'] as $data) {
        $value = $data['data']['value']['$'];
        $dimension = $data['dimensionValue'];
        /// insert $value and $dimension into database
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to get some data from it an insert it into a MySQL database.  My current code is technically working, but the API only displays the first 100 results.

If there's more than 100 results, it'll provide the data and give a header response of `206 Partial Content` to let me know there's more results.  To get the next page, I have to send `Page: n` in the header.

As you can see from the code above, I am sending `Page: 1` in the header.

How can I check to see if a `206` response code is given and if it is, keep looping through until it reaches a `200` response code (the page number in the header would need to be increased for each loop)?

Comment: Does the api provide a value of how many pages in total? Otherwise this sounds like you need a do/while structure.

Comment: Nope, the only way to know when you're at the last page is when you get a `200` response code :/

Comment: Damn. Yes you would need to `$i = 1; do { /* set headers, exec */ $i++; } while (curl_getinfo($ch)['http_code'] == 206)`. The code will exit the loop on the final page where 200 code given. Sorry I'm on mobile otherwise I would give more thorough code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that code inside a function and then call that function with 'n' as parameter based on the response code you get. Did you try that ? you can get the response code using curl_getinfo option CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE or CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE.